# Durandaljs and ASP.NET MVC 4 razor: data_bind attribute isn't converted to data-bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, durandal

using Durandaljs and ASP.NET MVC 4 razor, the data_bind attribute in the view (cshtml)  isn't converted to data-bind when rendered.

```
@Html.TextBox("txtDisplayName","", new { data_bind = "value: movieToShow.title" })
```

is rendered as

```
<input data_bind="value: movieToShow.title" id="txtDisplayName" name="txtDisplayName" type="text" value="">
```

but should be

```
<input data-bind="value: movieToShow.title" id="txtDisplayName" name="txtDisplayName" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling the built in [InputExtensions.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh429618(v=vs.108).aspx) and not some custom method? Because your code should work. In fact your exact code works in a newly created MVC4 project just fine.

Comment: Yes, a sample project is attached [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_Kblv6LiHWNZzZVS1pQTndLR00/edit?usp=sharing). Click File-> Save As

Comment: Your link is broken "Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists."

Comment: The file details.chshtm under App/views/movie has the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but now I can download the file but cannot open it because the length of the zip is 0 bytes.

Comment: ok works now, tested [link] (https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_Kblv6LiHWNOEdrTi00ZDRnUkk)

Comment: Your last link is still not working.